# Send SNS Topic when CloudFormation complete - Using Java API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I am using the AWS JAVA APIs to dynamically create/update CloudFormation stacks.  I would like to attach a an SNS topic and receive notifications when stacks are complete... however, I am not receiving SNS as I would expect.  Am I missing something?

```
    CreateStackRequest createStackRequest = new CreateStackRequest();
    createStackRequest.withStackName(stackName);
    createStackRequest.withOnFailure(OnFailure.ROLLBACK);
    createStackRequest.withCapabilities(Capability.CAPABILITY_IAM);
    createStackRequest.withNotificationARNs("sns topic arn I expect notifications to be sent to");
    createStackRequest.withTemplateBody(templateBody);
    createStackRequest.withParameters(paramList);

    cftClient.createStack(createStackRequest);
```

^^ I can manually publish an event to the topic and I get an email.  But when the code runs my stack is created and an SNS event is not sent.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not missing anything.  You've got that correct.  However, the execution role for the Lambda must have sns:Publish permissions for the topic.